# Trying to insert another label for a piechart in ChartsJS

Tags: javascript, charts, chart.js

I created this piechart using chartsjs. As of now, if you run the snippet, I am able to display my labels the following way:

```
Uno\Company 1
19
(56%)
```

However, I would love to display Company text underneath, so that it can be displayed like this:

```
    Uno
    Company1
    19
    (56%)
```

I tried creating a separate array: **label2: ["Company1", "Company2", "Company3"]**

Then in the callback, I added a new function, which i thought would give me the other label beneath, but no luck.  Here is the code I used for that:

```
title2: function(tooltipItem, data, label2){
   return data['label2'][tooltipItem[0]['index']]
}
```

Can anyone help me out?

```js
var ctx = document.getElementById("myChart");
var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
  type: 'doughnut',
  data: {
   label1: ["Uno\\Company1", "Dos\\Company2", "Tres\\Company3"],
    datasets: [{
      label: '# of Votes',
      data: [12, 19, 3],
      backgroundColor: [
        'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)',
        'rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.2)',
        'rgba(255, 206, 86, 0.2)'
      ],
      borderColor: [
        'rgba(255,99,132,1)',
        'rgba(54, 162, 235, 1)',
        'rgba(255, 206, 86, 1)'
      ],
      borderWidth: 1
    }]
  },
  options: {
    tooltips: {
      callbacks: {
       
        title: function(tooltipItem, data, label1, label2) {
          return data ['label1'][tooltipItem[0]['index']];
        },
        label: function(tooltipItem, data) {
          return data['datasets'][0]['data'][tooltipItem['index']];
        },
        afterLabel: function(tooltipItem, data) {
          var dataset = data['datasets'][0];
          var percent = Math.round((dataset['data'][tooltipItem['index']] / dataset["_meta"][0]['total']) * 100)
          return '(' + percent + '%)';
        }
      },
      backgroundColor: '#FFF',
      titleFontSize: 16,
      titleFontColor: '#0066ff',
      bodyFontColor: '#000',
      bodyFontSize: 14,
      displayColors: false
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<div>
  <canvas id="myChart" height="100"></canvas>
    <div id="chartjs-tooltip">
       <table></table>
    </div>
</div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.9.3/Chart.min.js">
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply change `label1` from an array of strings to an array of arrays:

```
label1: [["Uno", "Company1"], ["Dos", "Company2"], ["Tres", "Company3"]]
```

Chart.js will treat separate array items as separate lines.